# Magento - Add custom attribute to order and add this attribute to collection filter

Tags: php, magento

I follow the method mentioned in this link [Magento - Add custom attribute to order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599566/magento-add-custom-attribute-to-order?answertab=active#tab-top) like below

`<global>
...
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
                  <your_special_attribute>
                     <to_order>*</to_order>
                  </your_special_attribute>
            <sales_convert_quote>
    </fieldsets>
...
</global>`

to add new custom attribute to order and which is working fine. But the problem I am facing right now is when I use this attribute in collection filtering then it's not working for the below code..

`$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter("your_special_attribute", array("finset"=>'2'))->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');`